# compound subtraction in Java with different datatypes

Tags: java, integer, long-integer

I am confused about datatype conversion in Java. Why does this code work:

```
long q = 5;
long r = 4;

int p = 0;
p -= q * r;
```

while the code below gives a compile error?

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to int

```
long q = 5;
long r = 4;

int p = 0;
p = p - q*r;
```

How is explicit subtraction handled in Java as opposed to explicit subtration?

Answer (score -1):

`p -= q * r` succeeds for two reasons:

First, `q * r` is a compile time constant, and is known to to be within the `int` range.

Secondly, `a += b` is **not** the same as `a = a + b`, it’s the same as `a = a + (int)b`.

Combine those two facts and compiler knows what it can do safely.

Comment: Two reasons? And you managed to get them both wrong: 1) `q * r` is not a compile time constant, because they are not `final`. --- 2) `a += b` is the same as `a = (int) (a + b)`. not `a = a + (int)b`. --- Besides, the question already have many answers elsewhere, so shouldn't be answered here.